# VBA for Word: get comments from cells in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

There is a document with a table in it. Some cells - always in the first column - have comments. This code should go through all the rows and display the comments:

```
Sub GetComment()
    Dim vrsta, something As String
    For Each vrsta In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
        something = vrsta.Cells(1).Comments.Range.Text
        MsgBox something
    Next
End Sub
```

It doesn't. There are at least two problems:

1. if there is no comment in the cell, the program produces error
2. how do I get the current comment from this cell the program is at this moment?

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. This worked for me:

```
Dim ro As Row
For Each ro In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
    If ro.Cells(1).Range.Comments.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox ro.Cells(1).Range.Comments(1).Range.Text
    End If
Next ro
```